# Select query Logic sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have below table with data,

```
Emp_ID      Country_Code
101          AE
101          AE
102          AE
102          SG
102          AE
103          AE
103          AE
103          SG
103          SG
104          AE
104          AE
104          SG
104          SG
104          HK
```

If I GROUP based on Emp_Id and country, i can get result sets as below,

```
Emp_ID        Country_Code       count
101           AE                  2
102           AE                  2
102           SG                  1
103           AE                  2
103           SG                  2
104           AE                  2
104           HK                  1
104           SG                  2
```

I have 4 scenarios in this result sets,

1. Case 1: If I have only one Country_Code for a Emp_Id, no need to
   UPDATE the table for that Emp_Id. (eg., Emp_Id = 101)
2. Case 2: If the
   Country_Code count is same (in our case emp_id: 103), we need to
   UPDATE  country_code as "null" for that emp_id
3. Case 3: If the Country_Code count is different(in our case emp_id: 102), we 
   need to UPDATE highest country count Country_Code to for that Emp_Id.
4. Case 4: If the Country_code count is different (in our case emp_id: 104) and 
   highest count also more than 1, We need to update and country_code as null for 
   that emp_id.

**Expected Output**

```
Emp_ID      Country_Code
101          AE
101          AE
102          AE
102          AE
102          AE
103          NULL
103          NULL
103          NULL
103          NULL
104          NULL
104          NULL
104          NULL
104          NULL
104          NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #emp (Emp_ID INT,Country_Code VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #emp VALUES
(101,'AE'),(101,'AE'),  -- Case 1
(102,'AE'),(102,'SG'),(102,'AE'),   -- Case 3
(103,'AE'),(103,'AE'),(103,'SG'),(103,'SG'),    -- Case 2
(104,'IN'), -- Case 1
(105,'AB'),(105,'AB'),(105,'BC'),(105,'BC'),(105,'CD'),(105,'CD'),  -- Case 2
(106,'CD'),(106,'IJ'),(106,'IJ'),   -- Case 3
(107,'AA'),(107,'BB'),(107,'CC'),   -- Case 2
(108,'AE'),(108,'AE'),(108,'SG'),(108,'SG'),(108,'HK'), -- Case 4
(109,'ZZ'),(109,'ZZ'),(109,'YY'),(109,'XX') -- Case 3

UPDATE t
SET Country_Code = CASE WHEN cnt = 1 AND dst_cnt = 1 THEN Country_Code  -- Case 1
                        WHEN cnt > 1 AND dst_cnt = 1 THEN NULL  -- Case 2
                        WHEN cnt > 1 AND dst_cnt <> 1 THEN (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN cnt = lead(cnt) OVER( ORDER BY (cnt)) THEN NULL ELSE Country_Code END 
                                                            FROM ( SELECT Country_Code, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) cnt FROM #emp WHERE Emp_ID = t.Emp_ID
                                                                   GROUP BY Country_Code ) A WHERE cnt = 1) END -- Case 3 & 4  
FROM #emp t
JOIN (
    SELECT Emp_ID
        ,COUNT(cnt) AS cnt
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT cnt) AS dst_cnt
    FROM (SELECT Emp_ID
            ,Country_Code
            ,COUNT(Country_Code) AS cnt
        FROM #emp
        GROUP BY Emp_ID,Country_Code) a
    GROUP BY Emp_ID 
    ) b ON t.Emp_ID = b.Emp_ID

SELECT * FROM #emp
ORDER BY Emp_ID
```

Comment: Hi MJoy. Thanks for the Query. Really works good. And we have missed one more scenario which I have edited in the question. Can you please amend that scenario too.

Comment: @Srinivasan how is case 2 different from case 4 then ?

Comment: in Case 2: both country_code count is 2. So we are making it as "NULL" for that emp_id. However in Case 4: we have Country_code count as, AE=2, SG=2 and HK=1. In this scenario also, we have to update as "NULL" for that Emp_Id.

Comment: @Srinivasan sorry that was a typo, case 3&4 seems similar since the values are different and highest is more than 1

Comment: Yes MJoy. But in Case 3, we have only one highest value(ie AE=2), So we have updated that country_code(AE) to all of its Emp_Id. But in Case 4, we have more than 1 highest value , which is same,(AE=2, SG=2), so we cant pick the Highest country_code from this. Thats why I have added 4th scenario.

Comment: I could not handle Case 4. Is it possible to handle Case 4 in your same query.

Comment: @Srinivasan no worries, I'll see to it once I get back to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195920/discussion-between-mjoy-and-srinivasan).